# Prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

> Define the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as follows:
>
> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
>                 x \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & x\neq0 \\
>                 0 & x=0 \\
>             \end{cases}$$
>
> Prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

How do I even begin a proof of this nature?

Comment: Squeeze/sandwich theorem

Comment: How would I formally write out a proof for this?

Comment: A formal proof would just involve showing that the hypotheses of the squeeze theorem apply, then using it.

Comment: The first thing to do is to recall the **definition** of continuity.

Comment: Yes and in this case try the epsilon-delta criterion

Comment: You have to show that, $\forall\varepsilon>0\exists\delta>0$ such that, whenever $|x-0|<\delta$ we have $|f(x)-f(0)|<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Definition:** We will say that a function $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $a$ if

1. $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists,
2. $f(a)$ is defined, and
3. $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$.

**Proposition:** The function $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
  f(x) := \begin{cases} x \cos\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) & \text{if $x\ne 0$, and} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
is continuous at zero.

*Proof:*  From the definition of continuity, it is sufficient to show that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists, and is equal to $f(0) = 0$.  Observe that since $\cos(\theta) \in [-1,1]$ for all real numbers $\theta$, we have
$$ 0 \le |f(x)| = \left| x \cos\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \right| \le |x| $$
for all $x\ne 0$.  But
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} 0 = 0
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lim_{x\to 0} |x| = 0.$$
Therefore, by the Squeeze Theorem, we must conclude that
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} |f(x)| = 0 \implies \lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0, $$
which is what we wanted to show.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

---

An alternative proof, using the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity:

**Definition:**  We will say that a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $a$ if for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$ |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon.$$

**Proposition:** The function $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
  f(x) := \begin{cases} x \cos\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) & \text{if $x\ne 0$, and} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
is continuous at zero.

*Proof:*  Fix $\varepsilon > 0$, and choose $\delta < \varepsilon$.  If $|x-0| = |x| < \delta$, then we have
$$ |f(x) - f(0)|
= \left| x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - 0\right|
=  |x| \left| \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|
< \delta \left| \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|.
< \varepsilon \left| \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|.
$$
As above, observe that $\cos(\theta) \in [-1,1]$ for all real $\theta$, from which it follows that
$$ |f(x) - f(0)|
< \varepsilon \left| \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|
\le \varepsilon,
$$
which is what we wanted to show.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Answer (score 3):

$lim_{x\rightarrow 0}|f(x)|\leq lim_{x\rightarrow 0}|x|=0$. This implies that $f$ is continuous at $0$ since $f(0)=0$.

Comment: How do I formally write out an explanation for this?

Comment: You have $|cos({1\over x})|\leq 1$ implies that $|xcos{1\over x})|\leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments:
**Definition:** We say $f: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is *continuous at $x \in (a,b)$* if for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $y \in (a,b)$, if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$

So how do we start? We have $x=0$. **Let $\varepsilon>0$**. Let's put all that in the definition. We want to find $\delta>0$ such that, for all $y$ with $|y|<\delta$, 
$$\left| y\cos\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)\right|<\epsilon$$
How can we do this? Well, no matter what $y$ is, it's certainly true that $|\cos(1/y)|\le 1$...

Answer (score 0):

As $|\cos(x)|\leq 1$, it follows that $|x\cos(\frac{1}{x})|\leq |x|$, thus $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}|f(x)|\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}|x|=0=f(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\text{if}\quad \lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=f(0)\in \mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is continuous at $0$

$(\forall x>0)\qquad-1\leq\cos \dfrac{1}{x}\leq1\iff-x\leq x\cos \dfrac{1}{x}\leq x$

$(\forall x<0)\qquad-1\leq\cos \dfrac{1}{x}\leq1\iff x\leq x\cos \dfrac{1}{x}\leq -x$

With the squeeze theorem $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)\;=\;\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)\;=0$ since $f(0)=0$ $f$ is continuous at $0$